# Способ образования слова "убежище"

Tags: морфемы

подскажите пожалуйста, какой будет способ образования у слова "убежище"

Answer (score 6):

Чтобы определить способ словообразования, нужно дать определение слову. Что такое убежище? Убежище- место, куда можно убежать от опасности,значит, от глагола  "убежать" с помощью суфф. -ищ- - суффиксальный способ.